# Using Renv behind a proxy without password in plaintext

Tags: r, proxy, renv

I'm working on R projects behind a proxy server, which is why I use the keyring library to store my proxy credentials and to authenticate on the proxy manually whenever it is required. This way, I don't need to write `HTTPS_PROXY=http://usr:pw@proxy:port` somewhere in plaintext - neither in global environments nor project wise. Of course, on runtime, `Sys.env` does contain this string but at least only for the session.

So far so good. Now I need to use virtual environments because of some package version mismatches in my projects. For that I created `renv:init()`. After closing and reopining the package, Rstudio seems to freeze during loading the package. I guess `renv` somehow tries to reach the packages (some are on cran, some are on local gitlab), which cannot work as the proxy is not set.
When I create a `.Renviron` including the proxy settings with my username and password, everything works fine.

Do you know a way to prevent renv to try to connect to the package sources at project start? Or do you think the problem lays somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that `renv` is trying to make a request to the active package repositories on startup, as part of its attempt to verify that the lockfile + library are in sync. If that's the case, you could disable this via:

```
RENV_CONFIG_SYNCHRONIZED_CHECK = FALSE
```

in your `.Renviron`. See https://rstudio.github.io/renv/reference/config.html for more details.

Alternatively, you could tell `renv` to load your credentials earlier on in a couple ways, e.g.

1. Try adding the initialization work to either your project `.Rprofile` or (with `RENV_CONFIG_USER_PROFILE = TRUE`) your user `~/.Rprofile`;
2. Try adding the initialization code to a file located at `renv/settings.R`, which `renv` will source relatively early on during load.